# Session.set vs changing the variable

Tags: meteor

I have this template:

```
<body>
  {{> hello}}
</body>

<template name="hello">
  {{greeting}}
</template>
```

And this is the controller:

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
  Template.hello.greeting = "Hi";

  Meteor.setInterval(function() {
    Session.set("greeting", Values.findOne({}).value.toString());
    console.log(Values.findOne({}).value);
  }, 1000);

}
```

On the console I'm getting the value in the collection Values. However, when I `Session.set` it to `greeting`, the variable isn't updated on the HTML page. The "Hi" I default it to just stays there while every second I get the value that *should* be in it on the console.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try doing this:

```
Template.hello.greeting = function () {
  return Session.get('greeting');
});
```